# How ideal should the clock input be for registers built out of 74HC chips?

Tags: digital-logic, frequency, flipflop, register

I am a just starting my first build where a fully digital solution just isn't practical.

Basically I have an old laptop I want to give away but it doesn't have any backlight on the keyboard.

I have 2 Light Emitting Diodes (5V bus) wired into the monitor frame at an angle that casts a nice even lighting over the whole board.

I could have wired them into the computer for software control. But as a giveaway computer I want it hardware based and bulletproof. I'm certainly not into writing a custom BIOS.

Right now my idea is for a single tactile switch to toggle the lighting which will fit the frame quite nicely.

So what I'd like to do is for click 1 to turn on to 25% brightness, click 2 to go to 50%, click 3 to go to 75%, click 4 to go to 100%, and click 5 to turn them off again.

I'm working with 74HC series logic for the registers.

There are a lot of solutions to this problem but all involve (according  to the datasheets) MHz clock speeds that I'm not used to generating the old school way (I'm from the Atmel generation).

My question is how complex should my solution be here?

Is a ring oscillator good enough (not quite 50% duty cycle), or do I have to put in an order for a crystal?

As you can guess most of my builds are Atmel so I have 16 MHz laying around. But I need about 30 MHz which is right around what my AND gate oscillators ring at.

I figure for just detecting a switch pulse, unsteady duty cycle isn't going to blow anything up here. It would really save time and space to avoid any frequency doublers etc.

I'm also unsure as to whether that clock speed is even necessary. Would a logic chip like the 74HC series function on a 20 KHz clock, for example?

20 KHz will still give the user great response time as long as the chip can still function.

Let me know if I'm barking up the wrong tree with the 74HC series chips as well. They're just what I have in stock and I like to keep small orders to a minimum.

Thanks for your time guys,

Aaron

Comment: 74HC is digital, I don't see where you have an analogue flip flop here. Do you mean "discrete"? -- One possible alternative outside the discrete digital world is the usage of a small MCU like ATtiny or PIC12 in SMD 8-pin packages. Very small footprint, very small price tag, any behavior you can think of, including the option to control by the PC.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you mean by "analogue flip flop memory," since you haven't mentioned anything analog in the body of your question and I can't think of any possible thing that could be called "analogue flip flop memory."

Comment: Yeah sorry for the improper terminology. I just meant discrete digital design rather than analogue. The ATtiny is looking like the right solution here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For your purpose, the accuracy and stability of the clock is quite irrelevant, when looking to standard clock generators. You can even use a simple RC oscillator that has some percent deviation from its theoretical value and depending on the environment (supply, temperature, ...).

ICs of the 74HC series are quite fast, gates have nanoseconds propagation delay, flip flops have megahertz speeds, while going down to static operation without problem.

However, the effort to create a design to debounce the button, to step through the different levels, and to generate the control signal for the LEDs can be quite high, if you use discrete digital logic.

The actual necessary clock frequency depends heavily on your approach.

For example, if you use an R-2R network to control the DC current through the LEDs, you can get away with a low frequency or no clock at all. In the latter case you can use the debounced button signal as a clock for a simple finite state machine (a counter).

In another example, if you use PWM to control the brightness of the LED, you need a frequency high enough to get the required resolution (4 time steps in your case), without producing visible flicker.

Please be aware the DC current and brightness of LEDs have no linear correlation.

---

Picking up my comment, at the end of the day a small MCU like ATtiny or PIC12 is also "just" a collection of digital logic, including at least one finite state machine, counters, and for example an RC oscillator. All of this is in one tiny package.

The considerations about the frequency, accuracy and stability are applicable here, too. For example, many years ago I built a heating controller with 4 buttons, an LCD, and a PIC16 with a clock of 32768 Hz. I used a crystal, but only because the controller implemented a wall clock. However, the clock speed was more than enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't know why I never thought about using a discrete MCU instead of the whole development board. This solution makes a lot more sense.